# HR manager offered job over the phone, but didn't follow up

Tags: email, follow-up

Last week, a HR manager called me to offer me a position and told me that he would email me a letter of confirmation. However, it's been a week and I didn't receive anything. Should I call or email him to politely remind him? How might I phrase the email? I was thinking:

> Dear Mr X, As spoken over the phone last week, I am keen to embark on a career at Firm ABC. However, I am still awaiting the letter of confirmation. Could you send it to me at your earliest convenience? Thank you for your time.

Is that polite enough?

Comment: related personal anecdote: I once got a verbal offer but they were taking forever to make a formal offer, so eventually I resumed interviewing and got an offer elsewhere. I told the first place nvm I'm going to work elsewhere, and then they prepared a contract to sign within a day. sorry guys too late

Answer (score 10):

You've received a verbal offer. Now you are fully justified in being persistent in your follow-up.

I would make a small change to your email. Instead of "could you send it to me at your earliest convenience," try "how was the offer letter sent to me?" Assume that the letter was sent and something simply went awry in delivery.

I would also make a phone call before sending the email.

Comment: You should also use the company's handling of this as an indicator of whether or not they have their act together.

Comment: I would probably start with you should call before sending an email.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an in depth response to what to write in an email.

http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/03/01/how-to-write-an-email-that-will-actually-get-a-response/

But honestly if they have verbally offered you the job there is no reason not to follow up if it's been a week. Call him asking if he's sent it and verify the email address you gave him. Check your junk mail/spam before just to make sure not to embarrass yourself.