# Following up after company said they would hire me

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, internship, follow-up

I had an interview at a company about a month ago. They initially said they'd contact me within a week. After 10 days of silence, I wrote them asking about the status of my application. They said that I did well, had a high test score and that I'm on the list of people they want to hire (this is an internship position and they're looking to hire about ten people).

Two days later, they sent another email which I'm assuming was addressed to all the successful applicants, saying that they would email complete terms and more information within 14 days.

It's now been 19 days, the program is due to start in two weeks and my question is - should I write them and press them for information again? Or should I just accept that the HR department doesn't keep its own deadlines and keep waiting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HR manager offered job over the phone, but didn't follow up](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/hr-manager-offered-job-over-the-phone-but-didnt-follow-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write and point out to them that you're only writing because they mentioned 14 days and that right now, it's Day 19.

Make your query, and close it by wishing them well :)

What you are doing is called a "nudge", so be firm and gentle in how you communicate :)

Comment: In this case, yes you need to nedge. It is possible they mailed the information and it got lost so they think you are aware. Letting them know you haven't gotten it is important.

Comment: @HLGEM  Learning how to follow up effectively is one of the most essential skills that a professional needs to develop :)

Comment: I wouldn't send an email I would use the phone.  But an extra couple days often is caused by that critical person being out of town.  An email can be ignored, you harder to do that, with a phone call.

Comment: Thanks, I emailed them exactly what you said, will let you know what happens.